# непонятное поведение аргумента функции

Tags: c++

когда вызываю функцию прямо в ostream, не получаю нужный результат, а когда вызываю до cout, то все нормально...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;

string pop_word(const char*& p)
{
    const char* q = p;
    size_t count = strlen(q);
    string s = p;
    while (!isdigit(*q) && --count > 0) ++q;
    string str = s.substr(0, q - p);
    while (*q == ' ' && --count > 0) ++q;
    if (*q) p = q;
    return str;
}

int main()
{     
    const char* p = "unsigned  45678";
    const char* q = p;

    string s = pop_word(p);
    std::cout << s  << '\n' << p << '\n';
    // p указывает на "45678" (все нормально)

    std::cout <<pop_word(q) << '\n' << q;
    //почему  q указывает на "unsigned  45678"?
    return 0;
}
```

Заранее извените за плохо изложенный вопрос, и спасибо за внимание и ответ

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Наблюдаемое вами поведение вызвано тем, что ваш компилятор не удовлетворяет требованиям С++17 или работает в до-C++17 режиме.

До С++17 порядок вычисления аргументов в выражении

```
std::cout << pop_word(q) << '\n' << q;
```

был не специфицирован. Компилятор имел право сначала вычислить (подготовить, передать) аргумент `q`, а затем вычислить аргумент `pop_word(q)`. А мог поступить и наоборот. Так как `pop_word(q)` изменяет значение `q`, результат отличался бы в этих случаях.

Но начиная с С++17 левый операнд `<<`, как для встроенного, так и для перегруженного оператора, должен вычисляться до того, как вычисляется правый (спасибо @wololo за подсказку). Это означает, что в данном выражении вывод однозначен

```
unsigned  
45678
```

P.S. Что интересно, GCC в режиме `-std=c++17 -Wsequence-point` все равно продолжает предупреждать о неопределенном поведении в

```
int i = 0;
std::cout << ++i << ++i << ++i << std::endl;
```

хотя в С++17 никакого неопределенного поведения тут не должно быть.

Comment: После правки закралась не точность (мне кажется) в пост. Числа 1, 2, 3 могут быть выведены не только в любом порядке, но и не обязаны выводится в полном составе. Например, http://rextester.com/SGUL4400, три раза выводится 3.

Comment: @Croessmah: Здесь, скорее всего, срабатывают отличия от С++17. Именно начиная с С++17 вычисление каждого аргумента и все связанные побочные эффекты являются indeteminately sequenced по отношению к другим агрументам (хоть indeteminately, но sequenced!). Это означает, что порядок вычисления `++i` не специфицирован, но каждое `++i`, образно выражаюсь, заключено в персональную "изолирующую оболочку" по отношению к другим аргументам. В такой ситуации вывод `333` недопустим. Но, еще раз, это специфично только начиная с C++17.

Comment: Пример я, однако, уберу, потому что тут похоже есть тонкости С++17, которые гарантируют `123` (см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17). Причем они могут относиться и исходному примеру. Разбираюсь еще

Comment: где-то в стандарте я мельком натыкался на такое, но сегодня уже посмотреть не смогу.

Comment: @AnT, @Croessmah, относительно выражения `E1 << E2` стандарт C++17 говорит следующее: "The expression `E1` is sequenced before the expression `E2`".

Comment: По поводу PS: баг в [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83028) и такой же в [clang](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35340)

Answer (score 2):

В каком порядке будут вычислены операнды неизвестно.
В Вашем случае, сначала запоминается значение q, и только потом выполняется pop_word.
Выведите q в следующем statement'е, думаю, там всё нормально.

```
std::cout <<pop_word(q) << '\n';
std::cout << q;
```