# Возвращение значений функции. Порядок

Tags: c++

Есть код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num = 0;

int foo()
{
    return ++num;
}

int main()
{
    cout << foo() << ' ' << foo() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вот что мне не понятно:

```
cout << foo() << ' ' << foo() << endl; //Выводится "2 1"
```

и

```
cout << foo() << ' '; 
cout << foo() << endl; //Выводится "1 2"
```

В последней ситуации все ясно, но вот первую я не пойму (непонятен именно вывод).

Comment: Хм? Нам тоже непонятно, что вам непонятно.

Comment: Я новичок в этом деле еще, но как по действиям это происходит ?

Comment: Почему вывод 2 1 именно ?

Comment: [`2 1`, говорите?](https://ideone.com/BHE24W)

Comment: Проверял в visual studio и на сайте (там код компилируется и выполняется), да именно 2 1

Comment: https://ideone.com/SYdBfB - тут другой компилятор верно ? Вывод "2 1"

Comment: Во-о-от. Это я навожу вас на мысль о том, что один и тот же код по-разному себя ведёт на разных компиляторах. Что обычно означает, что у вас в коде UB (неопределённое поведение). По всей видимости, на компиляторах до стандарта C++17 это [правда так](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Про неопределенное поведение читал, но там были другие ситуации, в общем спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: [непонятное поведение аргумента функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768165/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, начиная с "классического" С++98 и до С++17 порядок вычисления подвыражений в этом примере не специфицирован. Поэтому никакого "как по действиям это происходит" тут нет и быть не может. По мере продвижения через С++11 и С++14 требования порядка ужесточались, но все равно их еще было недостаточно для того, чтобы вывод этого примера стал специфицированным.

Во-вторых, начиная с С++17 должно выводиться именно "1 2", но для этого нужно соответствие компилятора требованиям С++17.