# Dev C++ странно оперирует в cout с декрементом

Tags: c++, devc++

int t = 10;
cout << t << endl << t * 2 << endl << --t;

**выводит**: 9, 18, 9
***Почему?***

Comment: Добро пожаловать в мир неопределённого поведения. Вы не можете в одном выражении и читать переменную, и модифицировать её значение. Сначала создайте копию переменной (`int t = 10; int t_old = t; --t` или сразу `int t_old = t; t--`) и только потом читайте из неё (`cout << t << endl << t_old * 2 << endl << t;`).

Comment: Начиная с C++17, поведение вашего кода определено. Очевидно, ваш компилятор не удовлетворяет требованиям C++17. Подробнее здесь: [Непонятное поведение аргумента функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768165/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Comment: @wololo, поддержку C++17 надо включать явно. Да и пока в подавляющем большинстве случаев  нет необходимости в возможностях новейшей версии стандарта.