# Почему getchar() считывает с конца?

Tags: c++

```
cout <<(char)getchar()<< (char)getchar() << (char)getchar() <<endl;
```

В итоге после ввода последовательности из 3 символов,например ABC,вывод будет CBA.Почему?

[image: Последняя VS]

Comment: Ну почему же? См. https://ideone.com/ubrfPQ, например :)

Comment: Какой компилятор, какая ОС, какие опции компиляции? Ну и покажите например скриншот, чтобы мы вам поверили, а то вот пример от Harry выше опровергает ваши слова

Comment: прикрепил скриншот

Comment: Наблюдаемое вами поведение связано с порядком вычисления аргументов оператора `<<`. Подробный ответ можете посмотреть в [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768165/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).