# Непонятное поведение пост-инкремента C++

Tags: c++

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int ans = (n - 3) / 3; 
    cout << ans++ << " " << ans++ << " " << ans;
    
}
```

Входные  данные:
`9`

Выходные данные:
`3 2 4`

Вопрос почему? Ведь должно же по идее в порядке возрастания выводится?

Компилятор - MCVSC++

Comment: А какой стандарт в вашем компиляторе? Порядок вычисления при выводе, насколько я помню, определен стандартом начиная с С++17...

Comment: у меня не воспроизводится

Comment: Получилось воспроизвести в gcc 6.4 =)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [непонятное поведение аргумента функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/768165).

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch у меня на компиляторе Visual Studio это произошло

Answer (score 6, accepted):

До 17 стандарта тут неопределённое поведение, потому что в 1 выражении множество изменений 1 переменной, грубо говоря. Поэтому многие компиляторы с -std=c++98 выдают предупреждения. С 17 всё ок.

https://godbolt.org/z/5v4Pr5

Comment: В gcc c -Wall предупреждение таки имеется

Comment: @vp_arth вот более точный аргумент тогда *In a shift operator expression E1<<E2 and E1>>E2, every value computation and side-effect of E1 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E2*

Comment: @vp_arth емнип, то в gcc еще не прикрутили данное поведение и там это до сих пор ub.