# помогите с операцией a++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте изучал я значит постфиксные и префиксные операции и наткнулся на вот такую интересную штуку

```
int a = 1;
cout << a << endl << a++;
```

вот что выдает коносль:

```
2
1
```

это вообще как работает? a++ вроде должно увеличивать переменную после строки кода или нет?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/768169/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [непонятное поведение аргумента функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768165/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Починили в С++17. Настройте компилятор, чтобы использовал новый стандарт.

Answer (score 1):

Не определён строго порядок вычисления аргументов. Такая ситуация будет, если вы передаёте аргументы в функцию. Например, вы передаёте два аргумента в функцию. И порядок вычисления аргументов тоже не определён.

```cpp
# include <iostream>
void fu ( int const x , int const y ) {
  std :: cout << x << std :: endl ;
  std :: cout << y << std :: endl ;
}
int main(){
  int a = 1 ;
  fu ( a , a ++ ) ;
}
```

У меня вывело так :

```
2
1
```

Это значит, что сначала вычислился второй аргумент, а потом первый, и результаты отправились  в функцию.
В стандарте C++17 чуть-чуть поправили ситуацию когда использовали несколько равно-значных операторов, то-есть `operator <<`. И определили, что все аргументы должный были вычисляться по порядку слева направо. Ну а порядок передачи в функцию скобочной записью оставили пока также неопределённо.